# Connecting 2x halogen lights to a ECT T90 230/12V 50VA transformer which is operated by a step switch

Tags: wiring, transformer, halogen

I got this wall unit which has two halogen lights. The transformer is mounted on top of the wall unit and all the wires are there but no connections are made. The 2 lights are controlled by one step switch. Could someone be so kind as to assist me on where the connections need to be made ? pics are provided . The cable hanging over the side of the wall unit in the second pic is the step switch which is already connected . [image: transformer + 1st light at the far end of pic]
[image: 2nd light + transformer]
[image: transformer : ECT T90 230/12V 50VA]

[image: 1st light]

Comment: What is a "step switch"? That's not a term I'm familiar with. Is it, literally, a switch that sits on the floor that you step on to operate?

Comment: Well yes ,it is a switch you step on  , not sure what the correct term is used for it. But in this case the switch is attached to the side of the wall unit and is pressed instead of stepped on.

Comment: Somebody seems to have used bell wire for the 230V feed into the transformer.  That's wrong.

Comment: You might want to consider replacing the halogen lights with LED ones. You can probably find pre-wired ones or a kit that fits your existing openings. I personally find halogen fixtures like these to be annoying, and would take advantage of the opportunity to replace them.

Comment: Get rid of all that old garbage (risky, inefficient, consumable, expensive) and get some smart LEDs.